# Fast random normal distribution generator

Tags: c++, random, normal-distribution

I'm currently expanding a simulation model that relies heavily upon random normal distributed numbers. Currently it uses std::normal_distribution, but it's too slow.

Is there a way to implement a fast random normal distribution? The values don't have to be unique as long as it follows a normal distribution.

Comment: You will most likely not outsmart your standard library vendor significantly. And uniqueness contradicts normal distribution.

Comment: `std::normal_distribution` is a distribution, not a generator. Which generator and which compile flags are you using for which code? And of course, if the quality of the numbers is not that important, you could fall back to very simple algorithms, as simple as taking `r=++i%6`, for example.

Comment: @BaummitAugen you're absolutely right uniqueness contradicts normal distribution. What I had in mind when I said that is that it doesn't matter for me if it's 0.5556 or 0.5559 I can afford to lose some precision if it aids calculation.

Comment: @phresnel I'm using mt19937 (mersenne twister) as generator and -O3 -std=c++11 as compile flags. Falling back to another generator is not really an option, I inherited the model from someone else and I don't want to start playing with model parameters.

Comment: @Henk: You ask _Is there a way to implement a fast random normal distribution?_, yet _Falling back to another generator is not really an option_. Now, what is your issue, then?

Comment: A possible solution I had in mind was calculate 10,000 points beforehand and store them in a look-up table. Then select randomly from the look-up table when necessary.

Comment: But that's a solution you did not ask for. You asked for a generator. So basically you just stole 10 minutes of my time for not forming a proper question ...

Comment: Voting to close because now your question has become unclear.

Comment: @phresnel I'm sorry I mixed up distribution with generator. I could use a different generator, but I can't use a different distribution.

Comment: You are making it more and more unclear, unfortunately. Once you ask for a generator, then for a distribution, then for __workaounds__ __around__ your RNG.

Answer (score 5):

The [Ziggurat generator by Marsaglia and Tsang (JSS, 2000)](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v05/i08) has been seen to be both statistically sound and fast.  You do however want the revised Ziggurat normal generator which uses a better underlying uniform generator as per the comment of [Leong et al (JSS, 2005)](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v12/i07).

I have the original papers as well as a few review papers [in this GitHub directory](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppziggurat/tree/master/inst/papers) which is part of a Ziggurat C++ implementation for R.

Comment: See the comments on the question. He actually looks for a workaround and does not want to touch the RNG ...

Comment: Well the OP's last comment says "different generator, same distribution" which is what my answer provides.

Comment: Just in case I put here a link to the source code with fix by Leong - https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/c_src/ziggurat/ziggurat.html

Comment: That code is part of my repo for the R package which is already linked above:  https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppziggurat

Answer (score 3):

`std::normal_distribution` is a distribution, not a generator. You may want to try out other generator from the standard library and see what's fastest (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

If the quality of the numbers is not that important, you could fall back to very simple algorithms, as simple as taking `r=++i%6`, for example.

A [Linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) is easy to implement, too (actually, most standard `rand()` implementation use some implementation thereof. However, it will probably not be faster than using `std::linear_congruential_engine`. At the above linked site there's also a number of readily "configured" random number generators.

There's also an algorithm by the late Marsaglia, which can be found [here](http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/99/RNG) and which is quite efficient w.r.t. performance and number quality.

At the end, make sure to use proper optimization flags when testing for performance.

Answer (score 1):

The standard `<random>` library allows to produce random numbers using combinations of generators and distributions.  You are using the normal distribution, and what you want is a faster generator then the default, have a look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/).

Comment: See the comments on the question. Our answers are wasted efforts.